# plot a grid data on a background map in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, grid

I have data frame (MapData, see below) consisting of x,y and population. I would like to plot this data on a European map.

```
MapData <- array(0,dim=c(181*361,3))
MapData <- as.data.frame(MapData)
colnames(MapData) <- c("x","y","o3")

lat <- unlist(latGrid)
lat <- as.data.frame(lat)
lon <- unlist(lonGrid)
lon <- as.data.frame(lon)
o3 <- unlist(ulas)
o3 <- as.data.frame(o3)

MapData$x <- lon$lon
MapData$y <- lat$lat
MapData$o3 <- o3$o3
```

I would like to get a grid map where the country boundaries are the background and the zero value should appear as white.

How should i do this?

Regards

Comment: Anything you've already tried? Currently, your example is not reproducible (where do latGrid/lonGrid and ulas come from?)

Comment: i have tried spplot, ggplot, map (getMap)... The questoin can be generalized i think. if you have a lon,lat,value array and you want to plot this array gridded on a map, what would you do?

Comment: Show what you've been doing, and nobody can tinker when they don't have the data (I don't want to go search for it myself...)

Comment: You could have a look at the [cartography](https://github.com/Groupe-ElementR/cartography) package. Also there is plenty to be found on how to do this searching for "Choropleth in R".